# Show that $sr^i$ does not commute with $r^j$ where $1\le i,j\le n-1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> In a dihedral group $D_n=\{\langle r,s\rangle:r^n=1= s^2, srs=r^{-1}\}$ of order $2n$ show that 
>   $sr^i$ does not commute with $r^j$ where $1\le i,j\le n-1$.
>   Here $n$ is odd.

Suppose $(sr^i)r^j=r^j(sr^i)$
$\implies sr^{i+j}=r^j(sr^i)$

Now it is true that $r^js=sr^{-j}$

Using the above we have,

$\implies sr^{i+j}=r^j(sr^i)\implies r^{i+j}=r^{i-j}\implies r^{2j}=1$

Since $n$ is the smallest integer such that $r^n=1$ hence we have $n\mid 2j$

How to arrive at a contradiction from here?

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is false. If $n$ is even then $r^{\frac{n}{2}}$ is in the center of $D_n$ which means it commutes with all elements.

In your proof if we assume $j\ne\frac{n}{2}$ then we indeed get a contradiction because in that case $2j$ can't be divisible by $n$.